# Python scratch files in Pycharm - modules not being found?

Tags: python, pycharm

I'm new to Python and using PyCharm professional as my IDE. I have a small section of code that I want to work with from a longer file, so I created a "scratch file" with Python set as the interpreter. However, even just with importing modules I'm getting errors that the modules can't be found (even with standard modules). The file is set as a "Python" scratch file, so I'm not sure what else I need to do. The code I'm trying to run is:

```
from zipfile import ZipFile
import urllib

testfile = urllib.request.urlretrieve("https://ihmecovid19storage.blob.core.windows.net/latest/ihme-covid19.zip", "ihme-covid19.zip")
print("File saved at: " + (str(os.getcwd())))

with ZipFile('ihme-covid19.zip', 'r') as zipobj:
    print(zipobj.printdir())
    zipobj.extractall()
```

Everything is showing up with an error - no module urllib, no module zipfile, etc.

Comment: How are your packages installed for the larger project that this code comes from? Do you use a virtual environment?

Comment: Also, did you install the modules yet?

Comment: The packages are in Python's standard library so I didn't install them. I don't use a virtual environment. Everything works fine in the main file after importing.

Comment: As another hint, even if I write "print("some message")" I'm getting an error, unresolved reference 'print'. It seems like it isn't even reading the file as python code, although in settings it says using Python 3.7 interpreter

Answer (score 2):

This may come across like a non-answer, but I do think this is a bug in Pycharm.

I even downloaded an update, restarted pycharm, and rebuilt my indexes.  Same thing, here -- core Python modules are not registering as being importable (i.e. `import sys` or `import inspect` both failing type-checking).

[image]

We should probably move this to Pycharm's bug tracker.  For example:

- [Here is a similar issue around a specific import `NamedTuple`](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-47932/Unexpected-type-warning-for-typingNamedTuple-in-scratch-files)
- [Here's an issue around the default interpreter in scratch files](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/PY-42247/No-option-to-select-interpreter-for-scratch-files-with-multiple-attached-projects)

There may be a better existing bug ticket, so please do look and report back here -- I'll update this comment if someone finds or creates a better bug ticket on youtrack.jetbrains.com and shares the link.